# Can a coequalizer of schemes fail to be surjective?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, geometric-invariant-theory, examples

Suppose $g,h:Z\to X$ are two morphisms of schemes. Then we say that $f:X\to Y$ is the *coequalizer* of $g$ and $h$ if the following condition holds: any morphism $t:X\to T$ such that $t\circ g=t\circ h$ factors uniquely through $f$. The question is whether it is possible for a coequalizer $f:X\to Y$ to **fail** to be surjective.

**Remark:** $f$ must hit all the *closed* points of $Y$. To see this, suppose $y\in Y$ is a closed point that $f$ misses. Then $f$ factors through the open subscheme $Y\smallsetminus\{y\}$. It is easy to check (using the fact that $Y$ is the coequalizer) that $Y\smallsetminus\{y\}$ satisfies the universal property of the coequalizer. But coequalizers are unique, so we get $Y=Y\smallsetminus\{y\}$.

**Background:** A *categorical quotient* of a scheme $X$ by a group $G$ is the same thing as a coequalizer of the two maps $G\times X\rightrightarrows X$ (given by $(g,x)\mapsto x$ and the action $(g,x)\mapsto g\cdot x$) in the category of schemes. In [Geometric Invariant Theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=dFlv3zn_2-gC), Mumford defines the notion of a *geometric quotient* of a scheme by a group (Definition 0.6), which is stronger than the notion of a categorical quotient (Proposition 0.1). Part of the definition is that a map $f:X\to Y$ must be surjective in order to be a geometric quotient. In subsequent pages, he suggests strongly (but doesn't explicitly state) that a categorical quotient need not be surjective.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let $k$ be a field. Take $Y=\mathrm{Spec}\,k[[t]]$, and take for $X$ the disjoint sum of the closed subschemes $X_n:=\mathrm{Spec}\,k[[t]]/(t^n)$ ($n>0$). Put $Z=X\times_Y X$ with the two obvious maps to $X$. A coequalizer is just a direct limit of the system $X_1\hookrightarrow\dots X_n\hookrightarrow  X_{n+1}\hookrightarrow\dots$ in the category of schemes (look at the definition!).  Clearly, $Y$ is a direct limit in the category of *affine* schemes, hence also in the category of schemes since the $X_n$'s are one-point schemes and every compatible system of morphisms $(X_n\to T)_{n>0}$ must factor through an affine open subscheme of $T$.

So, $X\to Y$ is a coequalizer of $pr_1, pr_2 :Z\to X$, but its set-theoretic image is the closed point.

Comment: This is a beautiful example. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome!  I was waiting for an answer to this :)

Comment: Ah, finally an easy example! :)

Comment: @Martin: unfortunately it involves an infinite disjoint sum. I have another example which is separated of finite type, but not so "easy".

Answer (score 2):

This might lead to a pedestrian example:  Let $R$ be a local ring with maximal ideal $m$, $X$ a scheme, and $f:Spec(R) \to X$ a map.  If $U$ is an open subscheme of $X$ containing $f(m)$ then $f$ factors through a map $Spec(R) \to U$.  Thus if we have two arrows $g,h:Y \to Spec(R)$, the coequalizer $c: Spec(R)\to C$ must be an affine scheme (else $c$ would factor strictly through an affine neighborhood $U$ of $c(m)$, and $U$ would be a "better coequalizer" than $C$).  So If $Y=Spec(B)$ is also affine, then the coequalizer of $g,h$ is just $Spec(A)$ where $A$ is the equalizer of $g^\sharp,h^\sharp$.

let R be $k[x\_i]\_{(x\_i)}$ and $S'=k[y\_i,z\_i]\_{(y\_i,z\_i)}.$  there are two maps $g',h':R \to S$ given by

$$g'(x\_i) = y\_i$$

$$h'(x\_i) = z\_i$$

suppose that $I$ is an ideal of $R$.  let $I\_y, I\_z$ be the ideals generated by $g(I)$ and $h(I)$ respectively and let $S = S'/(I\_y + I\_z)$. write $g$ and $h$ for the induced maps $R \to S$.  the equalizer of $g,h$ is just $A = k + I \subset R$.  it seems unlikely to me that $spec R \to spec A$ is surjective for all choices of $I$.

Comment: Can you explain how you see that A/J is isomorphic to k[z]?

Comment: it isn't.  now i don't know whether this approach can work.  

Comment: This feels very promising. I really like the trick to show that the coequalizer of the spectrum of a local ring in the category of affine schemes is the coequalizer in the category of schemes. That alone gives a much better handle on the problem than I've ever had before.

Comment: Something perhaps useful to note... if $E\to R$ is the equalizer of $f,g:R\rightrightarrows B$ and $R$ is local, then $E$ is local and $E\to R$ is a local map: if an element of $E$ is invertible in $R$, its inverse is in $E$.

Comment: The approach using local schemes has led me to this http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24066/monomorphisms-and-epimorphisms-of-local-rings unanswered question.

Comment: Edited to fix incomplete LaTeX. If I destroyed anything, please fix as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if G is a simple complex Lie group, and N is its unipotent radical, then the natural map G -> G//N is not surjective.  The categorical quotient G//N is the Spec of a ring which is the direct sum of each irreducible representation of G once (this follows from algebraic Peter-Weyl).  This ring is graded by the positive Weyl chamber intersected with the weight lattice (its multi-proj is the flag variety).  Consider the point defined by the ideal generated by all non-trivial representations.  This isn't in the image of G (the group element above it would have to send all highest weight vectors to 0, which is impossible since G acts invertibly), but is a perfectly good element of G//N.

Though now that I think about it, this seems to suggest that the categorical quotient *isn't* the coequalizer in the category of schemes, but just in the category of affine schemes.  Which may be what's confusing you: sometimes you have to add more points to affinize the coequalizer of two maps between affine schemes.

Comment: As Anton said, a categorical quotient is by definition the coequalizer in the category of *schemes*.  This is a problem with your second paragraph, no?